# Scope issue when making POST request in Node.js

Tags: node.js, post, botframework

I am trying to make a POST request to access a QnA knowledge base from Microsoft Bot Framework. When I use Hurl.it to test my API I get the results I want, in this case the response "hello" to my question "hi". When I run the code my variables/callbacks seem to be out of scope somewhere. Error comes back null, and response.on('data'... or .end(... never gets called. I have tried http.request with no success either.

```
var request = require('request');

var responseStr = "";

 request({
        url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases/<kb>/generateAnswer",
        method: "POST",
        json: true,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type" : "application/json",
            "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key":"<sub-key>",
        },
        body: {"question" : "hi"}
    }, function (error, response, body){
        session.send("Error: " + error);
        response.on("data", function(chunk){
            responseStr += chunk;
        });
        response.on("end", function(){
           session.send("EndWith: " + responseStr); 
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
var postData = {question : "hi"};

var options = {
    host: "westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/",
    port: 443,
    path: "/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases/your_key/generateAnswer",
    method : 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key":"your_key",
    },
};

console.log(options);

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        callback(null, chunk);
    });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.write(JSON.stringify(postData));
req.end();
```

Comment: what is the purpose of callback(null, chunk);?

Comment: It returns the response from the request. If it's a JSON, you can use that :
 
`callback(null, JSON.parse(chunk));`

The null says that no error occurred.

Comment: I finally got this to work. My issue was that my postData was {"question":.... instead of {question: . Thank you

Comment: It works, but only some of the time maybe only 10%. The error I get says 
"BadArgument","Message":"Request body Is Null or Empty. But I only get this error sometimes which is a little odd.